# How do I force the field of a struct to be of some type?

Tags: racket

How can I enforce the type of the fields in this struct?

```
#lang racket
(struct Car (model year))
```

I've tried using a contract (but since I'm new to racket, this one doesn't obviously work... :P)

```
(provide (contract-out
      [Car (string? integer? . -> . Car?)]))
```

Example: This succeds but it shouldn't...

`(define my-car (Car 2008 "A3"))`

Sadly, it doesn't seem to be written anywhere how to get this done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're hitting at least one, and maybe both of the following:

1. Using `(provide (contract-out ....))` means the contract applies only at the module boundary -- only for *other* modules that `require` this one. So if your test example was in the same module, the contract would not apply. Instead you can use `define/contract` to make a contract apply to the thing itself, both in the module where it is defined and outside if you `provide` it.
2. There is a [special form of contracts for `struct`s](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/contracts-str), in which you specify a contract for each field.  What you tried above is a contract just on the constructor function. Although that *could* be what you want, consider using the contract for the `struct` instead.

Combining both you could do:

```
;; Define the contract on the struct itself.
;; Contract is used even within this module.
(provide car)
(define-struct/contract car ([model string?]
                             [year integer?]))
```

If you did want the contract to apply *only* at the module boundary, then you would use:

```
;; Define the contract only as `provide`d.
;; Contract is used only for code `require`-ing this module.
(provide (contract-out (struct car ([model string?]
                                    [year integer?]))))
(struct car (model year))
```

p.s. FWIW in Racket the common style is *not* to capitalize a struct name -- `car` not `Car`.

---

**Update**: Just to illustrate the difference more clearly:

```
#lang racket

(module mod racket
  (provide car0)
  (define-struct/contract car0 ([model string?]
                                [year integer?]))

  (car0 "foo" "bar") ;; gives contract violation
                     ;; because contract on struct itself

  (struct car1 (model year))
  (provide (contract-out (struct car1 ([model string?]
                                       [year integer?]))))

  (car1 "foo" "bar") ;; does NOT give contract violation
                     ;; because contract only on the `provide`
  )

(require 'mod)
(car0 "foo" "bar") ;; gives contract violation
(car1 "foo" "bar") ;; gives contract violation
```

Comment: BTW a cool thing about contracts is that they are not limited to "types" in a C/C++ sense. For example if the automobile were invented in 1769, then your contract for `year` could be `(and/c integer? (>/c 1768))` instead of just `integer?`. ;)